# How to Iterate to type: mimeType

Tags: c++

Hi I've a mimeType in ORTB, but couldn't pass compile, is there anyway to iterate banner.mimes and cast it to string?

```
cerr << "banner.mimes:" << banner.mimes.empty() << endl;
if (!banner.mimes.empty()){
    for(auto & mime : banner.mimes) {
       cerr << "banner.mime:" << mime << endl;
       std::vector<ORTB::MimeType> mimes;
       mimes.push_back(mime.toString());
       ctx.br->segments.add("mimes", mimes);
    }
}
```

it says:   error: cannot bind âstd::basic_ostreamâ lvalue to     âstd::basic_ostream&&â
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:581:5: error:   initializing argument 1 of âstd::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits, _Tp = ORTB::MimeType]â

Comment: 1. The `if` is completely redundant. 2. The error isn’t from the iteration, it’s from the `cerr << …` line. We need more context to be able to tell what’s causing this. But the definition of the `<<` operator for `MimeType` seems to be wrong because somewhere the stream is being converted to a `const&`.

Comment: I commented out the each line inside the for loop, but same error. ORTB::MimeType is from object Banner, I just need a way to get the object and convert it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

On line 5 you're declaring a vector of mimes, so line 6 should be `mimes.push_back (mime)`, or if you want the vector to contain strings you should change line 5 to `std::vector<std::string>`. Note that the call to `mime.toString ()` requires toString be a member of ORTB::MimeType.

For the error involving the ostream operator (<<) you need to provide a way for the compiler to convert MimeType to something compatible with ostream. I'm going to assume that  `mime` is an object of type `ORTB::MimeType`, but if it's not you just need to insert the appropriate class.
There are two ways you can do this: Either a member function of `ORTB::MimeType`:

```
namespace ORTB {
    class MimeType {
    // Class definition...
    public:
    std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream) {
    // output MimeType's information here: return stream << Value1 << Value2...; 
    }
}
```

Or by creating a similar function at a more global scope if you don't have access to the definition of `ORTB::MimeType`:

```
    std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const MimeType& mt) {
    // output MimeType's information here: return stream << mt.Value1 << mt.Value2...; 
    }
```

Note that with option #2 you need public access to whatever you're outputting. Ideally your data would be specified as private, so you would have to use public getters.

Comment: I put it inside the struct, it says: error: âstd::ostream& ORTB::MimeType::operator<<(std::ostream&, const ORTB::MimeType&)â must take exactly one argument

Comment: The struct is simple, I added toString(): struct MimeType {
    MimeType(const std::string & type = "")
        : type(type)
    {
    }
    //added
    std::string ToString() const { return std::string(type); }
    std::string type;
    //int val;
};

Comment: @DavidChange That's my bad: For the member function the 2nd parameter of MimeType is implicit. I've fixed the example. With more reflection on the mater, I think it would be best if you went with option #2 and defined it outside of the struct (probably underneath the struct's definition). The reason for that is that the member function doesn't fully extend the ostream operator, but defining it outside of the struct will.

Comment: @LanM it's a .h file, I put it outside of struct, a lot of other errors in other classes, how'd it cause it? Where's the one you fixed it without 2nd parameter within the struct?

Comment: @LanM it's a .h file, what do I output inside the ostream?

Comment: @DavidChange Where you put the function inside the struct doesn't matter as long as it's access specifier is public.
As for what you output into the ostream is up to you: What do you want to appear in your cerr << or vector of mime strings?

Comment: I used inline and outside of the struct, it's working. Thanks!